# Using SSR trying to render react code, facing issues with the correct classes not getting applied

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I am trying to render the react code on the server side. The code is being built and then rendered on the browser. But the classes that need to be added in the react code is being omitted. Can anyone please help me with what exactly is happening here.

This is how the code should appear but the classes are changed when the code is rendered

```
<div class="events-s">
    <div class="content-w">
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="event-section">Events</h1>
            <div class="feature-events">
                <h2 class="pb-block">Featured Events</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-w">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="pb-b">
                <div class="pb-b"></div>
                <h2 class="pb-block-t">Where We'll Be Next</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-w">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="pb-b">
                <h2 class="pb-block-t">Past Events</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how the code is actually rendered :

```
**<div class="main-content">**
        <div class="content-w">
            <div class="content">
                <h1 class="event-section">Events</h1>
                <div class="feature-events">
                    <h2 class="pb-block">Featured Events</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-w">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="pb-b">
                    <div class="pb-b"></div>
                    <h2 class="pb-block-t">Where We'll Be Next</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-w">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="pb-b">
                    <h2 class="pb-block-t">Past Events</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have added comment . As you can see the main class which is 'events-s' is changed to main-content

Answer (score 0):

This was solved .. i was not using the correct relative url to fetch the page
so the contents were not loaded correctly